# Shutterstock - "You do not have access to this route" Error

Tags: rest, shutterstock

I am trying to get image link from Shutterstock API, as described in the [docs](https://developers.shutterstock.com/documentation/licensing-and-downloading), but keep getting `"message": "You do not have access to this route. Please contact api@shutterstock.com for more information"` response.
I'm using correct `Subscription_id` and access token. Request URI is:

```
https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/licenses?subscription_id={{SUBSCRIPTION_ID}}
```

Request body:

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "image_id": "59656357",
            "format": "jpg"
        },
        {
            "image_id": "1079756147",
            "format": "jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've a paid monthly subscription, so everything should work. What could be wrong?

Comment: have you contacted api@shutterstock.com?

Comment: yes, it's been two weeks and now response

Comment: Sorry about that, @avalanche1. Try writing to apisupport@shutterstock.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutterstock recently started enforcing limitations on what free API accounts can do with the API. One of those limitations is that API search requests with a free account can't use the licensing endpoints. You don't automatically get full API access even if you paid for a subscription.

Look up your application at https://developers.shutterstock.com/user/me/apps and see what API product it uses. If it's "Free," you've got limited API access as described here:

https://developers.shutterstock.com/documentation/authentication#accounts-and-limitations

Sorry that you haven't gotten a response to the api@ address -- I'll look into it.

Comment: Yeah, I've got 'Free' dev account.
Plz look into it. Zero response really discourages from using the API.

Comment: @avalanche1 Write to apisupport@shutterstock.com or send me your email address and I'll make sure the API folks get your info.

Comment: mydogtrainingsecrets@gmail.com

Comment: I think you should amend the docs re 'Free' product and its limitations

Comment: Ok, you're in the support queue. Sorry about the delay getting back to you. 

Yep, definitely need to make this clearer in the dos. I've made some updates at this link; let me know if it's not helpful: https://developers.shutterstock.com/documentation/authentication#accounts-and-limitations

Comment: Thanks. But I would put the note about licensing to top or second from top in the list of Free acc limitations.